# How to suppress svg output by IJulia in Jupyter notebooks

Tags: svg, julia, jupyter, png, plots.jl

I use julia and Plots.jl in a jupyter notebook to create large scatter plots with up to 10^7 items. By default I get svg output, which makes Safari really sluggish. It also causes huge bloat in the .ipynb notebook file which stores the entire svg inline.

I specified format = :png and fmt = :png and get rasterised output in the browser. This helps to speed up things a lot. In the .ipynb file, however, I now see both the svg and the base64 encoded png, which makes the bloat even worse.

Converting my notebooks to pdf using nbconvert grinds to a halt in both cases.

I made some effort trying to using other julia plotting backends than the default one. This has mostly failed me due to installation woes (bad/outdated descriptions, not applicable to Mac, installations failing).

Google turns up a lot of results for the converse, i.e. people get rasterised output and want svg for higher quality. I specifically want rasterised output because this is much smaller and faster than the vectorised one in my use case.

Any pointers would be welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save picture to a file:

```
f = tempname()*".png";
p = Plots.scatter(rand(10^7), rand(10^7),markersize=1);
savefig(p, f);
```

Than display the file in the notebook:

```
using FileIO, ImageIO, ImageShow
FileIO.load(f)
```

The notebook size in mine case is 1MB - image included.

[image]

#### EDIT

After checking once again, you can provide mime type to `display` function to get the desired behavior:

```
display("image/png", p)
```

This seems to generate just png, not the slow svg.

Comment: Certainly. That's what I'm doing as a stop-gap. But it's a manual procedure and requires me to explicitly work through a file on disk. 
My request concerns the inline graphics in a jupyter notebook. These should not be saved as svg if displayed as png. Neither should the notebook save _both_ svg and png. There needs to be an option to stop inlining of svgs in ipynb files.

Comment: I just figured out you could try just provide MIME type for display - see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is really helpful as I can now stay within the interactive compute/display loop without having to hop through disk saves/loads. I verified that the .ipynb file indeed only contains the png after setting this. Can I set the MIME type globally?